# BTRFS send only new files without deleting anything on remote

Tags: filesystems, rsync, btrfs, zfs, replication

I'm looking into replacing rsync with BTRFS tools, but I'm not sure if what I want to do is even possible. I have a small local volume and a large remote volume used for archiving. Files will be deleted locally after a while, but should be kept on the remote end, so I only ever want to transfer the files that exist on the local volume, but never want to delete files on the remote that have been delete locally.

Is there an efficient way of achieving this with BTRFS (or ZFS for that matter) or should I just stick with rsync for this?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I have googled, but it seems like a hard thing to put into terms a search engine will return useful results for.

Thanks.

**Edit:** After further reading, I suppose this could be achieved by creating a new snapshot after files are deleted on the local volume and sending it without using the old snapshot to generate deltas? I think this would probably work, however it seems less efficient than using rsync.

Comment: or you could just rely on the fact that old snapshots on the destination will still have your old/deleted files.  retire snapshots quickly on the small system to save space, keep them for much longer on the larger backup system.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand, won't the newer snapshot with the files deleted take precedence? Wouldn't you still have to avoid sending the record of the deletion to the remote, like in my edit?

Comment: A snapshot is a copy of the filesystem (actually a list of all the blocks in use) at a particular point in time.  You can always retrieve data from older snapshots **until you delete them**.  And the blocks used by deleted or overwritten files aren't returned to the free pool until there are no remaining snapshots that use them.  That's why quick & lightweight snapshots are such a big feature for zfs and btrfs.

Comment: So, you can delete older snapshots from the small system.  leave them for longer on the bigger `btrfs/zfs receive`  backup system.  There are even tools you can use to automate rotation of hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, yearly snapshots (e.g. you can easily retain snapshots of the last 24 hours, 14 days, 8 weeks, and12 months all maintained independently)

Comment: http://snapper.io/ for btrfs, https://github.com/graudeejs/zfSnap for zfs. or google for btrfs or zfs snapshot management or similar terms.

Comment: Ahh I see, so I would have to mount the old snapshot to retrieve the files that were deleted in the newer one. I think I probably just need to set up a test system and have a play around with this. Thanks for the help.